# exporting test cases from TFS MTM to excel

Tags: manual-testing, mtm, excel, tfs

My company has recently migrated to TFS and I'm using Microsoft Test Professional 2015 (MTM) for my test cases.

I have created my test plan with requirement based suites to log my test cases against, but I'm struggling to see how I export the requirements and cases together.

I've had a look on SE but i'm unable to find a solution. I've also looked online for suggestions and I've come across a few tools such as http://exporttfs2excel.codeplex.com/ but this only seems to work for older versions and won't connect to the TFS server.

I've also tried using the team section on Excel but I'm only able to export my cases, but this is much help as they are not showing which requirement they relate to.

Has anyone ran into this issue and found a workaround?

Comment: I have half of a work-around.  As suggested below, use a TFS Query then add the column for `Steps` which will post a huge chunk of HTML into a cell.  I'm not sure what to do at that point though.

Answer (score 2):

The Team section on excel will allow you to connect to and export any TFS query you have access to. Queries will work against any TFS object that has a base type of Work Item.

Since a requirements-based test suite uses (in the Scrum template) Product Backlog Items and Defects to define requirements, you need to build a query in TFS that includes linked work items.

You'll want to start with the tree view, search for work item type of Any and filter that to work items with at least one child of type Test Case.

As I recall, Test Suites are also work items in TFS 2015, so you can use test suites as part of your filtering as well. The TFS query engine allows you to run the query as it stands, so you can keep testing it out until it shows you what you need, then save it with a descriptive name.

From there, connect to that query using the Excel Team menu, and you have your export.

Answer (score 1):

You can use TFS API to develop application like that. It allows customize a lot of item in MTM and TFS which you can not do with MTM or TFS.